# trouble with counter in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some trouble with my code. I'm trying to write a program that asks you a number to count down from. here is the code:

```
import time as ti

print("""Hello this is a countdown clock.
What would you like to count down from in seconds?""")

count_down_sec = input()

int(count_down_sec)

print(f"counting down from {count_down_sec}")

if count_down_sec > 0 :

    print(count_down_sec)

    ti.sleep(1)

    count_down_sec -= 1

else :

    print("error")

print("all done")
```

I keep getting an error that I can't use the `>` operator when dealing with str and int.

But I converted the string to an integer.

could someone help me figure this out?

Comment: `int(count_down_sec)` returns an integer, the `count_down_sec` variable is **not changed**. use `count_down_sec = int(count_down_sec)` to replace the string with the integer.

Comment: When you get an error, always cut & paste the exact error, rather than paraphrasing.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I'm pretty new to this all. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int(count_down_sec)` does not change `count_down_sec`.  You need to use the return value of the `int` function and assign it to `count_down_sec`.

```
count_down_sec = int(count_down_sec)
```